# Redirect message to the corresponding working thread/Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, reactive-programming, confluent-platform

I'm working with Kafka and trying to implement a single consumer which subscribe to all wanted topics. Let's say I have 3 topics (A, B, C). How to process messages from each topic synchronously, but between topics in parallel. So, for A topic I need process messages one by one, but at the same time I need process messages one by one from other topics.

It looks like I need separate thread for each topic. Could you please advice how it can be implemented? Are there some ready solutions for this? My consumer looks like

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    ConsumeResult<string, string> consumeResult = _consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);

    ... processing here

    _consumer.Commit(consumeResult);
}
```

I don't have any idea how to implement it because no experience with asnyc in C# yet. Found thing like Reactive Extensions https://gist.github.com/omnibs/6b2cbdba2685693448ee6779736a00c2.

When I receive a message, how to redirect message to the corresponding working thread/Task?

Using Confluent.Kafka 1.3.0 package to work with Kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var channels = new Dictionary<string, ActionBlock<ConsumeResult<string, string>>>();
foreach (var topic in _consumer.Subscription)
{
    channels.Add(topic, new ActionBlock<ConsumeResult<string, string>>(async consumeResult =>
    {
        ... processing here
        _consumer.Commit(consumeResult);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }));
}
```

this code will create [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-3.1) for all topics that you subscribe.

then when you receive a message, redirect it to the corresponding channel

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
   ConsumeResult<string, string> consumeResult = _consumer.Consume();
   await channels[consumeResult.Topic].SendAsync(consumeResult);
}
```

Read articles from @PauloMorgado answer

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), namely the [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) or [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/).

Answer (score 0):

You should create 1 obserable for each topic onto which to publish messages.  Then subscribe to each available topic on the observer.

[Create a IObservableList from a list of IObservable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512500/create-a-iobservablelist-from-a-list-of-iobservable)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in acync, could you please give some example?

Comment: I am not sure I have understood which part of the problem you are trying to solve. Are you using reactive extensions?  Is the IObservable already defined? If the IObservable is already defined then we need to understand how it is defined in order to give a helpful answer. Or are you trying to implement the IObservable (as I have assumed here.) If you are not using reactive extensions what is you input?

Comment: No, I don't use Rx. I actually don't have any code to solve this issue. I just found that Rx canbe helpful in this case

Comment: What is the source (DataStructures/entry points) of the data, what format is it in? I agree that RX may be the way to go. Your code example does not give enough information to understand the context.